# ActiveRecord sort_by model's association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord

I want to use a where clause to retrieve all the correct ItemAttributes, then sort by the column `order` in Static.

**Relationships:**

```
class ItemAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :static, primary_key:"name", foreign_key:"name"
end

class Static < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item_attributes, :foreign_key => 'name', :primary_key => 'name'
end
```

Code that doesn't quite do it...

```
      @items = ItemAttribute.where(level:5)
      @sorted = @items.sort_by(&:static.order)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like using scopes and keeping specifics of each class in it's class, for something like this I could add a scope to `Static` model,

```
class Static < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :sort_by_order, -> { order(order: :desc) } # or asc if you want
end
```

Then use that scope in the query

```
@sorted_items = ItemAttribute.joins(:static).where(level: 5).merge(Static.sort_by_order)
```

Comment: thanks! This is the only answer that didn't return an error for me. Next level type stuff here!

Answer (score 0):

@sorted_items = ItemAttribute.include(:static).where(level:5).order('statics.order')